# « Article in press » en français

Tags: traduction, science

Quelle tournure française peut interpréter la tournure anglaise

> article in press

[In fact, articles in press are accepted, peer reviewed articles that are not yet assigned to volumes/issues, but are citable using DOI.
Selon le consignes de [CNU](http://www.cpcnu.fr/) *peer reviewed articles* s'interprète *articles dans des revues internationales avec comité de lecture*.]

Je pense à

> article en cours de parution

mais je ne sais pas si c'est acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut simplement dire « article en cours de publication ». Je ne me rappelle pas avoir entendu une autre expression.

Comment: Ce n'était pas précisé dans la question mais si c'est pour une bibliographie, il est aussi possible d'utiliser « à paraître ».

Comment: Non, c'est plutôt pour un CV et un exposé.